# Ubuntu Software not showing information about any package (infinite spinner)

Tags: package-management

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and noticed that Ubuntu Software (version 3.38.1) does not show content of any package:

[image]

Just this infinite spinner...same happens for installed packages and .deb files when I double click on those.

Installing via apt works though...but this is annoying...any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!